# Finding every kth element in the list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function in Haskell function which would keep every kth element in the list.

```
> keepl 2 [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[4,6,8]
```

I have tried the below function but the output is showing inconsistency.I want the list to come as [3,6] but it is coming as [1,5,9]

```
keepl k [] = []
keepl k (x : xs) = x : (keepl k $ drop k xs)

main = do
 print $ keepl 3[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: What did you try? You can solve this using recursion on the list, using a "current index" argument, for instance.

Comment: Nice, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Yeah.. I am trying but so far I haven't get it correct..So need some help

Comment: @Bond007: it is not a problem that it is not correct, it is a problem that you do not show any attempt. You do not discuss what you have tried, nor why that did not work.

Comment: dr n [] = []
dr n (x : xs) = x : (dr n $ drop n xs)

main = do
  print $ dr 1[1,2,3,4,5]                                                                                                                                                                                                                           I have tried the above function, but its actually dropping elements even though I want to keep it.

Comment: @Bond007 you should edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, because this sounds like a homework problem.  But here’s a hint: if you `let (y:ys) = drop (k-1) xs`, `y` is the next element to add to the list, and you can call the function recursively, with `k` and `ys` as the arguments, to get the rest.  The base case that terminates the recursion will be when `length xs < k`.

You had the right idea by writing a recursive function.  You don’t want the first element of the result to be the first element of the list, but rather the `k`th, so don’t add the head of the input list before you `drop`.

There are other possible approaches, but recursive is simplest (and probably most efficient).  Some more excessively clever ones: `map last . unfoldr (\xs -> if length xs < k then Nothing else Just (splitAt k xs))`.  The call to `unfoldr` repeatedly calls the helper function, which splits the list into chunks of length `k`, discarding any leftovers.  Then the `map` takes the final element of each chunk.  Or generate a list of indices and map `!!` onto each.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library, this work work

```
import Data.List.Split
let keepl k x = map last $ chunksOf k x
```

Otherwise if this is an exercide for learning haskell and you want to rebuild the wheel, this would work:

```
import Data.List

keepl k n [] = []
keepl k 1 (x:xs) = x : (keepl k k xs)
keepl k n (x:xs) = keepl k (n-1) xs

main = do
 print $ keepl 3 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: FTR, `chunksOf n = map (take n) . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)`. Can also implement that yourself and use it... However, the first solution doesn't give the right results, e.g. `keepl 3 "abcd"` gives `"cd"`. The second in unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you function does give every *k*-th element (actually, every *k*+1-th element, because you drop *k* and also keep one)... just, it starts out with the head, i.e. takes elements [0, *k*, 2·*k*+1, 3·*k*+2...]. That's because the `keepl k (x:xs) = x : ...` clause prepends `x` to the result, no matter what.

If instead you want to only take the element *after* dropping some, write that out:

```
keepl k xs = case drop k xs of
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the original list into sub lists of length `k`, using [splitAt](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt):

```
splitlists :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitlists _ [] = []
splitlists k xs = first : (splitlists k rest)
    where
        (first, rest) = splitAt k xs
```

So a call such as:

```
splitlists 2 [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Would result in :

```
[[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9]]
```

Then take the last element of every sub list of length `k`, and add them to a new list:

```
keepl :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
keepl _ [] = []
keepl k xs = [last x | x <- splitlists k xs, length x == k]
```

Example calls:

```
> keepl 2 [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[4,6,8]
> keepl 3 [3,2,1,4,5,6,9,8,7,10]
[1,6,7]
```